# How to pause the child process and how to read data from it?

Tags: python

[Process window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOXOl.png)

I am able to send data to the process. While passing value i need to read specific data.
**"Test station with name  is already registered"** this value from the window. 
If this value found then i need pass key value 'y' and 'enter' from keyboard.

How to check this condition?

Here is the code:

```
command = os.path.join(self.skynet_exe_dir, self.skynet_exe)
s = subprocess.Popen(command)
result = s.communicate(input=[hotkey('ctrl','r'),press('enter'),press('enter'),press('y')])
print(result)
```

This code is not returning any value after passing all input. But all the inputs are passing to the window.

Once passing all inputs, execution window ask above question if already registered machine is available. Here i need to read this value.
How can i pause the execution window and read data from it?

Once reading is done again i need pass values to window by resuming the execution.

please help me.

Comment: How are you connected to the command prompt? Are you running this from the command prompt and want to send data back?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you please provide your Python code? And I'm not sure why you would want to send a Ctrl-R to the command prompt. Did you want to put a Ctrl-R in the file?

Comment: @IainShelvington i am running one exe file which opens command prompt and asks input from user. Here i need to send ctrl+r for new registration and above provided inputs. At the end i need to send ctrl+y to save the details.

Comment: @rajah9 not yet written. i don't have idea how to write it using python.

Comment: Let's make this more clear. Is the `Ctrl+R` really to be sent to a *command prompt*, or is it sent to an input of the `exe` file? (The first goes to Windows, the second goes to the application.) My Windows command prompt does no action on a `Ctrl+R`, it just shows `^R` in the line. Is that what you want?

Comment: @RoryDaulton Yes. Once running exe file it opens command prompt there by showing application started successfully. If the user wants to register the machine there he/she need to send **Ctrl+R** . After this it asks the inputs to user in that window it self. **Note:** This is not normal command prompt window. This is application command prompt window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use keyboard library.

Below is sample code -

```
import keyboard

def act():
    print("act")

keyboard.add_hotkey("ctrl+r", act)

# Blocks till you press escape
keyboard.wait('esc')
```